# lxml in python, parse from url

Tags: python, lxml, python-2.7

I am novice to lxml. I want to download the web page and get interested data from, my code is:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = "http://www.example.com/"

html = urllib2.urlopen(url)

root = etree.parse(html) # the problem is here
```

can anyone explain me why it is wrong?

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yatego.py", line 10, in <module>
    root = etree.parse(html)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2942, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54187)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1550, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79703)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1580, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:80012)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1463, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78908)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1019, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75905)
  File "parser.pxi", line 564, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71739)
  File "parser.pxi", line 645, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72614)
  File "parser.pxi", line 585, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71955)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'mdash' not defined, line 4, column 21
```

This code:

```
url = "http://www.example.com/"

res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.parse(res.content)
```

gives this error:

```
File "yatego.py", line 11, in <module>
    doc = lxml.html.parse(res.content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 692, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2942, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54187)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1528, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79485)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1557, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79768)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1457, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78843)
  File "parser.pxi", line 997, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75698)
  File "parser.pxi", line 564, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71739)
  File "parser.pxi", line 645, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72614)
  File "parser.pxi", line 583, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71927)
IOError: Error reading file '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>IANA &mdash; Example domains</title>
```

This code:

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(url)
```

works fine

So where is the problem?

Comment: What is the problem ? What did you expect and what did you get ?

Comment: what error message do you get? what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is the exception:

```
IOError: Error reading file '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  ...
```

Youre passing the content of a file to a function that expects a path to a file.
Same reason `doc = lxml.html.parse(url)` works, a url "is a" filepath.

Does the following work better?

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
```

Comment: You mean this is wrong: res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.parse(res.content)

Comment: yes, the line where you assign to `doc` is wrong (unless I'm wrong) and should look as I posted.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `lxml.html` to parse HTML instead of `lxml.etree`.

You can also open the url directly with `lxml`:

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(url)
```

Sometimes `lxml` will have trouble dealing with HTTP's quirks, in which case you'd need to use a more robust solution to fetch pages, like [`requests`](http://python-requests.org):

```
res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.parse(res.content)
```

Comment: This will work a little bit better. Not entirely sure if it works with lxml.html.parse, but I know it works with lxml.etree.parse.
res = requests.get(url);
doc = lxml.html.parse(res.`raw`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html.read()` to begin with: HTML is not a string type. Also, you should really check if the URL downloaded properly, as this is by no means assured.

UPD. Use `html.parse(filename_or_url)`